# How does Kant solve the problem of the difference between phenomenon and noumenon?

Tags: kant

[I'm sorry for my incorrect English]
Hello, I studied the Critique of Judgment of Immanule Kant, and I don't understand, how Kant solve the problem of the difference between Critique of Pure Reason and Critique of Practical Reason (phenomenon/noumenon, understanding/reason, determinism/freedom).
if it doesn't bother you, can someone help me?

Comment: Too many questions all at once for me. How about sticking to the one in the title?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, I made only one question.

Comment: You ask also about phenomenon/noumenon, understanding/reason and determinism/freedom. I would suggest just sticking to the first pair. .

Comment: Ok, I thought, that when Kant answered in the Critique of Judgment at the first question, he answered at all those question.

Comment: You might be right, but it makes life difficult for anyone trying to answer. Or maybe it's just me. Let's see what other say..

Comment: Related [Is noumenon to phenomenon for Kant what substance is to accident for Aristotle?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/17571/9148) It is not very clear what "the  problem of the difference" is, he rather uses the distinction between the pure and practical reason to resolve the apparent problems, between determinism and freedom, etc. See also [Kant's Distinction Between Theoretical and Practical Knowledge by Enfistrom](http://www.harvardphilosophy.com/issues/2002/Engstrom.pdf).